# How to copy data from one array of object having some similar property and value to another usestate array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to copy only those property which is already declared in `useState` array, like this:

```
const SellDashBoard = () => {
  const[userData, setUserData] = useState({
    name: '',
    age: '',
    number: '',
  })

  const data = {
    name: 'Ram',
    age: '21',
    village: 'pithawaiaya'
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserData((pre) => {
      return { ...pre, ...data }
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

The result is: `{ name: "Ram", age: "21", number: "", village: "pithawaiaya" }`

I want result as `userData` `{ name: "Ram", age: "21", number: "" }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
setUserData((pre) => {
  return { ...pre, name: data.name,age:data.age }
})
}, [])
```

Keep every other thing in the object the same and update only the other attributes that you want to change.

We can also make a function that returns an updated object and then we can use useState to update new object. All we are doing in the method is comparing the two objects with the `keys` and if the key exists in the `useState` object then simply update that and leave everything else. I think this should do the job.

```
   function updateObject(finalObj, data) {
    for (const key in finalObj) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        finalObj[key] = data[key];
      }
    }
    return finalObj;
  }
useEffect(() => {
    const updatedObj =updateObject(userData,data)
    setUserData({...updatedObj})
  }, [])
  console.log("finally",userData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of shallow copying all of the `data` object's properties into the `userData` state, create a shallow copy of the previous state to update and iterator over the `data` object's keys to explicitly check if it is a property of the state, and if it is, overwrite the property.

Example:

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  name: "",
  age: "",
  number: ""
});

useEffect(() => {
  setUserData((pre) => {
    const nextState = { ...pre };

    for (const key in data) {
      if (nextState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        nextState[key] = data[key];
      }
    }

    return nextState;
  });
}, []);
```

```js
const data = {
  name: "Ram",
  age: "21",
  village: "pithawaiaya"
};

const SellDashBoard = () => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    age: "",
    number: ""
  });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setUserData((pre) => {
      const nextState = { ...pre };

      for (const key in data) {
        if (nextState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          nextState[key] = data[key];
        }
      }

      return nextState;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(userData)}
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <SellDashBoard />
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a function that will check if the key in useState exist in data then copy it if not then empty string. Try this implementation

```
setUserData((prev) => {
      // convert the previous data to array of keys
      const dataKeys = Object.keys(prev);
      // create new instance of an object
      let newData = {};
      for (let key of dataKeys) {
        /* 
          this is to check if keys in previous state exist in new data.
          if exist then copy if not empty string
        */ 
        newData = { ...newData, [key]: data[key] ?? "" };
      }
      return newData;
    });
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Your excpected output state you wanna be excact similar with your `data` obj, so the best solution i think is to declare the `data` obj in your current `useState` and delete the `useEffect` hook.

```
  const data = {
    name: 'Ram',
    age: '21',
    village: 'pithawaiaya'
  }

const SellDashBoard = () => {
  const[userData, setUserData] = useState(data)

  return (
    <div>
     
    </div>
  )
}
```

You will place the `data` obj outside from your `component` - `SellDashBoard` or you can move it in outside file and you can import it as well.